# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined on the login page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, error-handling, typeerror

I'm doing a login page with JWT and trying to redirect the page once log in to the home using this.props.history.push("/") but I get this typeError: Cannot read property 'push'of undefined. I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```js
class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          email: "cihemzine@gmail.com",
          password: "test",
      };
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
      this.setState({
          [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
      });
  };

  login = () => {
      const { email, password} = this.state;
      axios("/users/login", {
          method: "POST", 
          data: {
              email,
              password
          },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
        
          console.log(response.data);
          this.props.history.push("/");
          
      })
      .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
      });

  };
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
             <div className="container">
                
        <input  value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChange} className="form-control mb-2 mt-4"name="email" type="text"placeholder="Your email" />
        <input value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange} className="form-control mb-2"name="password" type="password" placeholder="Your password" /><br></br>
        <button onClick={this.login}className="text-center btn btn-light">LOGIN</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default Login;
```

Comment: When you `console.log(props.history)` what do you see ?

Comment: it says props is not defined

Comment: Did you check that in props you have nothing like 'history, match etc'?

Answer (score 1):

If you have nothing like 'history, match etc' in your props you need to check that you use your login component as Route

```
<Route path ='' component={Login} />
```

If you don't use Login in such way and can't for some reasons.
You can use HOC or hook for you component to add history to your component.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom"
or
import { withRouter } from "react-router";
```

Comment: I'm using the login as route like so : 
      <Route path="/login">
        <Login />
   </Route>

Comment: Try to use it like `<Route path="/login" component={Login}/>`. Then you render it as a child you can use children as render method and pass props like history manually.

Comment: Link to documentation with sample https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/children-func